# Seeking advice how to process this nested JSON/Object

Tags: javascript, json, nested-object

I have a nested JSON and want to end up with the result array, how is this possible? Any tips on how i can accomplish this? Do i need to use a nester for in/of loop? Higher order functions etc? I am new to nested objects, any tip or good reference will be appreaciated!

// const db shows the desired result once db.save() is called. I want it
to include the Date, Symbols (USD etc.) and the value of it - all wrapped inside their own object

```
const db = [
{ Date: '1999-01-05', AUD: 1.8944, SEK: 9.4025, USD: 1.179 },
{ Date: '1999-01-06', AUD: 1.882, SEK: 9.305, USD: 1.1743 },
```

];

// the json that i recieve upon fetching

```
const json = {
rates: {
    '1999-01-08': {
        AUD: 1.8406,
        SEK: 9.165,
        USD: 1.1659,
    },
    '1999-01-06': {
        AUD: 1.882,
        SEK: 9.305,
        USD: 1.1743,
    },
    '1999-01-07': {
        AUD: 1.8474,
        SEK: 9.18,
        USD: 1.1632,
    },
    '1999-01-05': {
        AUD: 1.8944,
        SEK: 9.4025,
        USD: 1.179,
    },
},
start_at: '1999-01-05',
base: 'EUR',
end_at: '1999-01-10',
```

};

Comment: Why is that your expected result? What is the logic that takes your object to the `db` array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using nested `for` loops and [Object.entires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a key/value pair from your object. It creates an array of objects just like your desired result. (Not in the exact order, as Javascript doesn't care for keeping objects sorted).

```
function save(data) {
    const db = []
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.rates)) {
        rate = { 'Date': key }
        for (const [_key, _value] of Object.entries(value)) {
            rate[_key] = _value
        }
        db.push(rate)
    }
    return db
}
```

Usage; in your posted example, would be:

```
db = save(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, i didn't get it to work as i probably messed something up or explained poorly, apologise. But seeing you using nested for loop helped me figure out this approach which resulted in every currency and exchange rate from a specific date to be in one object with only key values.

```
        const db = [];
    for (const prop in json.rates) {
      Object.keys(json.rates[prop]).forEach((element) => {
        const obj = {
          date: prop,
          symbol: element,
          rate: json.rates[prop][element],
          base: json.base,
        };
        db.push(obj);
      });
    }
    console.log(db);
```

enter code here

```
enter code here
```